# what is wrong with the loops

Tags: c, performance, optimization, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am solving a problem of adding the last digits of numbers lying between a range (for ex. between 'm' and 'n' where m < n).I have coded this

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
 int t=0;
 long int m=0,n=0,num=0,sum=0,lsum=0,i=0;
 scanf("%d",&t);
 while(t--){
    scanf("%ld%ld",&m,&n);
    i=m;
    while(i<=n){
       while(i!=0){
          num=i%10;
          i/=10;
       }
       lsum=lsum+(sum%10);
       i++;
    }
}
printf("\n%ld",lsum);
return 0;
}
```

Here t=No of Test Cases. m and n is the range. I don't know why it is running infinitely in the terminal. I am using gcc(4.3.2) compiler.How can I optimize it for speed ,or is it the case where the while conditions are never terminated, but why?

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger, stepping through the code line by line? The you could easily check conditions and variables, to find out what the problem might be.

Comment: Use a `for` loop, preferably of the form `for (i=0; i<SOMETHING; i++)`. This form is really hard to get wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dividing the `i`: `i/=10`. This means that `i` is always set back to `1` at the end of the loop. You should use a temporary variable for the dividing.
Like this:

```
    while(i<=n){
       int temp = i;
       while(temp !=0){
          num=temp %10;
          temp /=10;
       }
       lsum=lsum+(sum%10);
       i++;
    }
```

P.S. There are many other errors in your code. But they are not connected with the infinite looping.

Comment: its not going infinite now.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is an infinite loop int the code :

```
 while(i<=n)
 {       
     while(i!=0)
   {        
      num=i%10;        
      i/=10; 
   }       
   lsum=lsum+(sum%10);       
   i++;    
 }
```

the first while(1<= n) is always true : the second loop makes i = 0 or i = 1 !